# Why does navigator variable in Chrome show Mozilla/Gecko in some places?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, navigator

I am trying to detect what browser a user is using my web app on and, interestingly, when I check the `navigator` variable, it shows me some values like this -

[image: navigator variable in Chrome console]

Now I don't understand why `appCodeName` is 'Mozilla' and `appName` is 'Netscape'
Also, why is `navigator.product` showing 'Gecko'?

Could someone decode this please?

Comment: because all browsers (IE and Edge too) want to be Mozilla

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [WHATWG](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#The_WHATWG)'s [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-navigator-object), `navigator.appCodeName` *must* return `Mozilla`, and `navigator.appName` *must* return `Netscape` (i.e., all modern browsers return the same values). These values are deprecated, and going forward, will be removed altogether. The only reason they are still around is for backwards compatibility; their removal could break an app that depends on them. As with other web standards, we are in a bit of a transitional phase.